# Decrypt asymmetric key encrypted using openssl, oaep padding mode

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography

I have my Symmetric generated using following command

`openssl rand 32 > test.key`

And it is encrypted using my public key as shown below command. It uses OAEP padding mode.

`openssl pkeyutl -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -encrypt -inkey public.key -pubin -in test.key -out test.key.enc`

But when i am trying to decrypt using my private key it gives me Bad padding error.

My Java  Code

```
    // few imports  

  private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(final String privateKeyFile)
      throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    final KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(PayboxUtil.ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
    final PemReader reader = new PemReader(new FileReader(privateKeyFile));
    final byte[] pubKey = reader.readPemObject().getContent();
    final PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pubKey);
    return keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);
  }  

  public static byte[] decryptRandomKey(final byte[] encryptedKey, final String private_key_file)
      throws NoSuchProviderException {
    try {
      final Key privKey = getPrivateKey(private_key_file);
      final byte[] ciphertext = encryptedKey;     
      final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
      final OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-512", "MGF1",
          new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSpecified.DEFAULT);
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey, oaepParams);
      final byte[] symmetricKey = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
      return symmetricKey;
    } catch (final Exception e) {    
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't work, Madhav, you can only use the @ sign for pinging people that have already commented. Besides that, this is not a site where you can request specific people to help, we're not payed consultants here. Please put the **full** stracktrace in your question and indicate where the exception happens in your code. I'm also missing the symmetric encryption part I think.

Comment: ```final byte[] symmetricKey = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext); ```    this code throws exception  gived BadPadding exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used below Oaep  parameter spec

`new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA1", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);`

It decrypys but the checksum didnt match.

But using the decrypted symmetric key i can decode the encrypted files. I found a good documentation on openssl pkeyutl

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/pkeyutl.html

Comment: Since neither the label nor the MGF1 digest is explicitly specified in the OpenSSL statement, the default digest is used, which is SHA-1 in both cases. For this reason, decryption works with the configuration posted in the response. Which checksum are you talking about?